Is this proof rigorous enough?
Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $f$ map $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is continuous at $c$ in $A$. Show for any $\varepsilon > 0$ , there exists a $\delta$-neighborhood of $c$ such that if $x,y$ are any points in the intersection of the $\delta$-neighborhood and $A$, then $|f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon$.
Proof: Let $f$ from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $c$ in $A$. Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f (x) - f (c)| < \varepsilon$ when $|x - c| < \delta$. Let $V$ be a $\delta$-neighborhood of $c$ and $E$ be an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $f (c)$. Since $f$ is continuous at $c$ in $A$, for any $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $f(c)$ there exists a $\delta$-neighborhood of $c$ such that if $x$ is in the $\delta$-neighborhood, $f (x)$ is in the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood. So if $y$ is in the $\delta$-neighborhood of $c$, then $f(y)$ is in the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $f (c)$. Let $V'$ be a $\frac{\delta}{2}$-neighborhood of $c$ contained in the intersection of $V$ and $A$ such that $x, y$ are in $V'$. Then $|x - y| \le |x - c| + |y - c| < \frac{\delta}{2} + \frac{\delta}{2} = \delta$. Since $|x - y| < \delta$, this implies $|f (x) - f (y)| < \varepsilon$. QED.


Please make your question body self-contained by explicitly (re)stating the question there. 2. I've added the solution-verification tag because that's what you're asking. I'll further quote from the tag description: '"Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.' We don't do full proof checking.


"Let V′ be a δ2-neighborhood of c contained in the intersection of V and A"  Why should any such thing exist?.... Here's three hints.  1)  If $W$ is a number, than so is $\frac 12 W$.  2)  If $a$ is $k$ away from $b$, and $b$ is $m$ away from $c$ then how far away are $a$ and $c$ from each other.  and 3)  $\frac 12W + \frac 12W = W$.

It exists because I desperately wanted a solution to this problem to not hate myself, but yea the entire reason that line is in there is to apply triangle inequality and get epsilon in the end :/

Let's step through this a line at a time.

Proof: Let $f$ from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $c$ in $A$.

Good start.

Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
$|f (x) - f (c)| < \varepsilon$ when $|x - c| < \delta$.

That's the correct definition of continuity, although you don't need to state this explicitly.

Let $V$ be a $\delta$-neighborhood of $c$ and $E$ be an
$\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $f (c)$.

You lose me here.  What are $\epsilon$ and $\delta$? To apply the definition, of continuity, you need to choose $\epsilon$ and then use the definition of continuity to note that there exists a $\delta$ such that so and so.  So I would start with something like "Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Choose $\delta$ so that..."

Since $f$ is continuous at $c$ in $A$, for any
$\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $f(c)$ there exists a
$\delta$-neighborhood of $c$ such that if $x$ is in the $\delta$-`neighborhood, $f (x)$ is in the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood.

OK, that's another definition of continuity.

So if $y$ is in the $\delta$-neighborhood of $c$, then $f(y)$ is in
the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $f (c)$.
Let $V'$ be a $\frac{\delta}{2}$-neighborhood of $c$ contained in the
intersection of $V$ and $A$ such that $x, y$ are in $V'$.

What is $x$ here? You have only mentioned $y$ so far.

Then $|x - y| \le |x - c| + |y - c| < \frac{\delta}{2} +
 \frac{\delta}{2} = \delta$.

OK.

Since $|x - y| < \delta$, this implies $|f (x) - f (y)| < \varepsilon$. QED.

This doesn't follow.  Actually, this is what you are trying to prove. The definition of continuity only at $c$ only says that we can guarantee that $f(x)$ is close to $f(c)$ by making sure $x$ is close to $c$. There's no mention of $c$ here, so you can't apply this.
Hint, instead of considering $\delta/2$, you should start with "Let $\epsilon > 0$.  By continuity, we may choose $\delta > 0$ so that if $x$ is in the $\delta$-neighborhood of $c$ then $f(x)$ is in the $\epsilon/2$-neighborhood of $f(c)$."

Thank you so much for this. These problems are so confusing to me. For problems of proving existence, is it correct to attack the thing we know should hold for any choice? Like how in this case were proving there is a delta neighborhood for any choice of epsilon?

I'm not sure I understand your question - but since your are proving a statement of the form "For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that..." your proof should follow the pattern "Let $\epsilon > 0$.  ... Choose $\delta$ such that..."

Something seems incorrect. The value of $\delta$ needs to be selected more carefully.

Since $|x - y| < \delta$, this implies $|f (x) - f (y)| < \varepsilon$

This is not necessarily true. You are not told that $f$ is continuous at $x, y$; the values of $\delta, \varepsilon$ apply to the point $x = c$.
Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary.
Since $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for each $x \in B_d (c, \delta)$, we have $f (x) \in B_d \left( f (c), \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon \right)$. (*) For two elements $x, y$ in this ball, we of course have $|f (x) - f (c)|, |f (y) - f (c)| < \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon$. Therefore, by the triangle inequality, $|f (x) - f (y)| \le |f (x) - f (c)| + |f (c) - f (y)| < \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon + \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon = \varepsilon$, as desired.
The key idea is that points within a ball of radius $\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon$ must be within $\varepsilon$ of each other, so this is used as the criterion to select the required neighborhood in the domain.
(*) Here, we are taking $B_d$ as balls in the subspace $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. For $a \in A$, it is true that $B_d (a, r) = A \cap B'_d (a, r)$, where $B_d' (a, r)$ is the $r$-ball centered at $a$ in the space $\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you for the feedback. I kind of knew the last line didn't feel right, but I just needed the satisfaction of that little square at the end :D
